# Xcode & iPhone -- creating a warning prompt when attempting to install an app with a newer deployment target

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment-target

We're in  the process of submitting our first iOS game to our publisher. We got a bug back from their QA department that basically states that when attempting to install our game (deployment target: 4.2) through itunes, onto a decice that does not meet the minimum os requirements (in this case a device running 3.2.2), the game doesn't install (which is good), but the user isn't prompted with any message that tells him or her why (their ios is out of date, what ever)

This took me a bit out of left field. Is this a common thing? I wasn't aware that i even had control over this process. If anyone out there could shed some light on this situation, I'd be pretty greatful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you've set the required iOS version correctly in your build, the App Store and iTunes are responsible for presenting the user with appropriate applications for their device and providing the messaging that Apple sees fit to provide.

Is your publisher experienced with iOS applications?

Comment: yes, our publisher is quite experienced, which is really why I'm posting here, as opposed to assuming it was out of my hands. I'm getting the feeling that they're dealing with an external QA team, although I would imagine that they'd have been around the block a few times themselves!

Comment: oh, and just to make sure -- setting the required iOS version means changing the Deployment Target, is that correct?

Comment: You have to set it in two places, in the target and the project. Yeah, weird.